# Red zone fuel level

Tags: diesel, fuel-tank, peugeot

When the fuel level in my car comes to the red zone I feel the running more heavy, the car needs more throttle and is more difficult to gain speed. Is this something normal??

Comment: How old is your vehicle? Diesel or gasoline?

Comment: @Daniel Peugeot diesel year 2006

Comment: Was the fuel filter ever changed?

Comment: @Daniel yes 6 months ago

Comment: And did the problem only occur after that?

Comment: @Daniel I dont know for sure I noticed that recently,,usually i dont drive with low fuel level

Answer (score 2):

The fuel tank might be dirty, causing issues with the fuel pump picking up enough fuel.

Also, some vehicles don't like been driven on empty tanks and this can often result in poor performance or stuttering as you attempt to accelerate.

I'd have the fuel tank removed and cleaned. I would also replace fuel filters for good measure.